# Change view size to match drawn shape

Tags: android

Within the onDraw() method of the view, I paint a small line.  When the view is dynamically added to my layout, it takes up the entire screen.  How can I make sure the view is the size of my line that I drew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Constructor write this :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WidthOfYourLine,HeightOfYourLine);
    this.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: That doesn't go in the `onDraw()` method. It goes in the constructor.

Comment: Sourab, yahoo!  I swear I tried this before and didn't work :)

Comment: Ted, yes, I figured this out as otherwise it drew to the screen size first and then changed to the specified dimensions.  Thanks!